# Jquery toggle .css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jquery code which runs fine.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.menuBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains('is-active') === true) ? this.classList.remove('is-active'): this.classList.add('is-active');
        $('nav').slideToggle();

        $('.headerBarm').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('nav').toggleClass('fixed-position');
        $('.headerBar').toggleClass('fixed-position');


        $('body').css({
            'height': '100%',
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });

    });

});
```

Recently I added the last line.

```
$('body').css({
                'height': '100%',
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            });
```

When i click on the button the above css gets added.

My problem is, when i click it again it doesn't change back. Could this work with a toggle kind of ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you continue your streak of classes and `toggleClass()`?

CSS:

```
body.full {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS (replace that last line):

```
$("body").toggleClass("full");
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted so quickly? Please explain.

Comment: @mplungjan I guess that could be why. But I'm no code ninja that can copy a post and edit it in four seconds...

Comment: @mplungjan It's not about being "even" (I'm not much of a hardcore rep-gamer), but I was just wondering why it could be. But the downvote has been reversed. The last six comments are now irrelevant :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom class and toggle it.

```
.myclass {
  height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}



$('body').toggleClass('myclass');
```

Comment: CSS classes don't have quotations around them.

Comment: @JonathanLam Thanx